# Is it possible to export all the command line output to a file without manually redirecting via > symbol?

Tags: python, unix

I have a python (2.7) script that has various `print` statements and other things. Now, I want to export the entire command-line output to a file. As most people know, this is very easy to do manually using the below command:

`script.py > file.txt`

But I want to make `> file.txt` also as a part of my python script itself instead of having to redirect manually every time the script is run.

I tried using the `with` command but it only exports a specific object out into a file but not all the `print` statements, dataframes, and etc.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm not well-versed in unix or python. Can someone please help me with some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the sys module and add the following line at the begin of your code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. And, one small question on similar lines.. Is there a way to tweak this so that the output is both shown on the command line as well as be exported to the file?

Comment: believe that given the request it would be useful to take a look at this module [https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html] it allows greater flexibility for your logs, more clean and precise than redirect print